# Generic factory (?) pattern in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a generic class:

```
class SomeValue[T](private val value: T) {
  override def toString = value.toString
}
```

In my application, I'm going to be using a particular construction of this class a lot:

```
val five = new SomeValue[Int](5) // doing this a lot
assert(five.toString == "5")
```

This is pretty verbose and prone to typos (for example setting it to 6 by accident). To solve this, I'd like to create a class that masks this pattern:

```
class Five { ... }
```

So that I can now do this:

```
val five = new Five
assert(five.toString == "5")
```

Kind of a dumb example I know, but hope you get the picture!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are building constants, hence I would suggest using [Scala objects](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html).

e.g.

```
object Main extends App {
  assert(Five.toString == "5")
  assert(Hello.toString == "hello")
}

class SomeValue[T](private val value: T) {
  override def toString = value.toString
}

object Five extends SomeValue[Int](5)
object Hello extends SomeValue[String]("hello")
```

Comment: I think I simplified my example too much, class is more suitable for my case. But thanks for the answer, clarified what I needed to know! It wasn't intuitive that I could give arguments in the class definition, is there a name for this concept?

Comment: Yeah, if you need class, you can do `class Five extends SomeValue[Int](5)`, scala classes are parameterized with constructor arguments and the type can be implicitly inferred. You can find some details [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just define a method instead of a whole new class?

```
class SomeValue[T](private val value: T) { ... }
object SomeValue {
  // since the class appears to be immutable, it could also be a val
  def five = new SomeValue(5)
}

// elsewhere
SomeValue.five
```

Naturally, this method can have arguments and type arguments if desired (e.g. to fix only some of constructor arguments).

Comment: I considered this, but I wanted a tighter type signature `:Five` that I could elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this right after posting my question.

```
class Five extends SomeValue[Int](value = 5) {}
```

Seems right, but can anyone confirm?